# IDEA sends "personal data" when pushing on GitHub

Tags: git, github, webstorm

I developed my app, then committed and pushed on GitHub (I'm a newbie in version control). Then due to an unrelated problem I had to manually add my GitHub repo into workplace using CLI.

I set up a new project and pushed another change. It appeared OK, but when I checked up the repo, I saw many strange xml files in the root directory. I found out that these were my **Webstorm settings** like interface settings, theme, github info etc ("personal data"), as they were committed with **WS-11.0.3 <%my_username% Create file.template.settings.xml, phonegap.xml, IntelliLang.xml, ide.general.xml, web-browsers.xml, git.xml, keymap.xml, Default.xml, diff.xml, laf.xml, other.xml, debugger.xml** message (it is phonegap project).

After update these files appeared in my local project root too (where they obviously shouldn't be).  Deleting them and pushing empty commit throws an error, which is claiming that merging is needed. Moreover, deleting these files resets some of my WS settings (color scheme for example).

I tried adding them and whole .idea/ in .gitignore, but that didn't help. Creating a new project from scratch doesn't work as WebStorm doesn't have feature to add remote repo manually. I have to checkout project files from the repo I work with, BUT a clean project with a new clean repo works fine)

[It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oxP7.png)

Comment: Are those files actually captured in source control?  Use `git ls-files | grep .xml` to find out.

Comment: Exactly what error message do you get when you `git rm` the xml files, commit, and push? This is usually the right procedure for removing unwanted files from version control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have misconfigured your [Settings Repository plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7566) and it pushes your IDE settings into the project's repository instead of its own.

Similar case: https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5566999#5566999